# How to set Id for EditorFor() html helper in asp .net MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, editorfor

I used this to override framework generated id 
 `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cost, new { id = "checkCost" })`
But unfortunately id is not changing. i.e 
When i use
 `string d = Request.Form["checkCost"];`

at controller action then string filled with null value.
WHY?? I also replaced EditorFor with TextBoxFor but nothing changed then also controller takes **cost as ID**

```
<td >
        @Html.DropDownList("check_master", "--select package--")
    </td>
    <td >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.check_name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.check_name)
    </td>
    <td >
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cost, new { id ="checkCost" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cost)
    </td>
```

**Updated:**

- This is my partial view and my main view(rendering partial from ajax.actionLink) also hold a EditorFor(model=>mode.cost)
- Partial view is strongly typed to Check_master table and main view is strongly typed to package_master where both entitySet hold same name property i.e "COST" Secondly both partial and main view hold EditorFor "cost"
  I tried to change the name of check_master property like by
- [Column("check_cost")]

public Nullable cost { get; set; }
But dont know why this is not working i.e property naem is not changing while referring it like

```
model.something
```

Comment: Why do you want to change the Id? Using the default Id enabled the default model binding to occur. That is Request.Form["cost"] binds to the property cost

Comment: b'coz this is my partial view and my main view(rendering partial from ajax.actionLink) also hold a EditorFor(model=>mode.cost)

Comment: Why do you have two Text Boxes for the same property on the same view? Essentially you have two places to edit the same property. If the textbox is in the partial view take it out of the main view.

Comment: partial view is strongly typed to Check_master table and main view is strongly typed to package_master where both entitySet hold same name property i.e "COST" Secondly both partial and main view hold EditorFor "cost"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create 2 view models with properties CheckCost and PackageCost that way there's a seperation:

```
public class CheckViewModel{
   public string CheckCost{get;set;}
}

public class PackageViewModel{
   public string PackageCost{get;set;}
}
```

This way avoid conflicts.

Comment: Thanks @heads but i am seeing some way in my asked context

Answer (score 0):

To specifically answer the question asked, try this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.cost, new { @id = "checkCost" })
```

Note the slight (but important) difference: ... new { @id = "checkCost" })